# Could not instantiate implementation: com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.thrift.CassandraThriftStoreManager

Tags: cassandra, titan, gremlin, tinkerpop, gremlin-server

I have downloaded Titan from the link

[https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/wiki/Downloads]

and I started Titan using titan.sh start.

Got this:
Forking Cassandra...
Running `nodetool statusthrift`... OK (returned exit status 0 and printed string "running").

```
Forking Elasticsearch...
Connecting to Elasticsearch (127.0.0.1:9300)..... OK (connected to 127.0.0.1:9300).
Forking Gremlin-Server...
Connecting to Gremlin-Server (127.0.0.1:8182)..... OK (connected to 127.0.0.1:8182).
Run gremlin.sh to connect.
```

Started gremlin shell using gremlin.sh , gemlin shell has started .
But when I ran the below command , i got the below error..

gremlin> graph = TitanFactory.open('conf/titan-cassandra-es.properties')

```
Could not instantiate implementation: com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.thrift.CassandraThriftStoreManager
Display stack trace? [yN] y
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate implementation: com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.thrift.CassandraThriftStoreManager
        at com.thinkaurelius.titan.util.system.ConfigurationUtil.instantiate(ConfigurationUtil.java:55)
        at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.getImplementationClass(Backend.java:473)
        at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.getStorageManager(Backend.java:407)
        at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.configuration.GraphDatabaseConfiguration.<init>(GraphDatabaseConfiguration.java:1320)
        at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.open(TitanFactory.java:94)
        at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.open(TitanFactory.java:62)
        at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory$open.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:110)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:122)
        at groovysh_evaluate.run(groovysh_evaluate:3)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:215)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Interpreter.evaluate(Interpreter.groovy:69)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:215)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Groovysh.execute(Groovysh.groovy:185)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:215)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Shell.leftShift(Shell.groovy:119)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:215)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner.work(ShellRunner.groovy:94)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.super$2$work(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:130)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:150)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.work(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:123)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:215)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner.run(ShellRunner.groovy:58)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.super$2$run(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:130)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:150)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.run(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:82)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:215)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.Console.<init>(Console.groovy:144)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:215)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.Console.main(Console.groovy:303)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at com.thinkaurelius.titan.util.system.ConfigurationUtil.instantiate(ConfigurationUtil.java:44)
        ... 46 more
Caused by: com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.TemporaryBackendException: Temporary failure in storage backend
        at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.thrift.CassandraThriftStoreManager.getCassandraPartitioner(CassandraThriftStoreManager.java:208)
        at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.thrift.CassandraThriftStoreManager.<init>(CassandraThriftStoreManager.java:186)
        ... 51 more
```

If any one knows about this please tell If i miss any configuration changes

**update 1:**

GREMLIN SERVER Log:

```
24245 [main] WARN  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer  - Graph [graph] configured at [conf/gremlin-server/titan-berkeleyje-server.properties] could not be instantiated and will not be available in Gremlin Server.  GraphFactory message: GraphFactory could not instantiate this Graph implementation [class com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory]
java.lang.RuntimeException: GraphFactory could not instantiate this Graph implementation [class com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory]
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.GraphFactory.open(GraphFactory.java:82)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.GraphFactory.open(GraphFactory.java:70)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.GraphFactory.open(GraphFactory.java:104)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GraphManager.lambda$new$27(GraphManager.java:50)
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedEntrySet.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:671)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GraphManager.<init>(GraphManager.java:48)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.ServerGremlinExecutor.<init>(ServerGremlinExecutor.java:94)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.<init>(GremlinServer.java:88)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.main(GremlinServer.java:290)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.GraphFactory.open(GraphFactory.java:78)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate implementation: com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.astyanax.AstyanaxStoreManager
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.util.system.ConfigurationUtil.instantiate(ConfigurationUtil.java:55)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.getImplementationClass(Backend.java:473)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.getStorageManager(Backend.java:407)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.configuration.GraphDatabaseConfiguration.<init>(GraphDatabaseConfiguration.java:1320)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.open(TitanFactory.java:94)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.open(TitanFactory.java:74)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.util.system.ConfigurationUtil.instantiate(ConfigurationUtil.java:44)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.TemporaryBackendException: Temporary failure in storage backend
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.astyanax.AstyanaxStoreManager.ensureKeyspaceExists(AstyanaxStoreManager.java:572)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.astyanax.AstyanaxStoreManager.<init>(AstyanaxStoreManager.java:291)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.exceptions.PoolTimeoutException: PoolTimeoutException: [host=127.0.0.1(127.0.0.1):9160, latency=10005(10005), attempts=1]Timed out waiting for connection
    at com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.SimpleHostConnectionPool.waitForConnection(SimpleHostConnectionPool.java:231)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.SimpleHostConnectionPool.borrowConnection(SimpleHostConnectionPool.java:198)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.RoundRobinExecuteWithFailover.borrowConnection(RoundRobinExecuteWithFailover.java:84)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.AbstractExecuteWithFailoverImpl.tryOperation(AbstractExecuteWithFailoverImpl.java:117)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.AbstractHostPartitionConnectionPool.executeWithFailover(AbstractHostPartitionConnectionPool.java:352)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftClusterImpl.executeSchemaChangeOperation(ThriftClusterImpl.java:146)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftClusterImpl.internalCreateKeyspace(ThriftClusterImpl.java:321)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftClusterImpl.addKeyspace(ThriftClusterImpl.java:294)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.astyanax.AstyanaxStoreManager.ensureKeyspaceExists(AstyanaxStoreManager.java:567)
    ... 24 more
```

Comment: Hmm, Update 1 says it is from `cassandra.log`, but you would not be able to find that stack trace in `cassandra.log`. That is a stack trace from `gremlin-server.log`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your Cassandra cluster/node isn't running correctly. I've never used `titan.sh` but I'd probably look to verify that Cassandra is booting cleanly and staying up.

Comment: i can understand cassandra is not running, when i check process running at cassandra port , nothing displays.. so how to resolve this problem ??

Comment: cassandra is not started and I can see an error in cassandra log :

Answer (score 1):

The message in the log file indicates that the Gremlin Server tried to instantiate a graph configured in `conf/gremlin-server/titan-berkeleyje-server.properties`. This is probably configured in your `gremlin-server.yaml` file under `graphs->graph`.

You already stated in your question that you want to use a graph configured in `conf/titan-cassandra-es.properties`. So just change that in the `gremlin-server.yaml`.

Comment: i have changed the properties file still getting same error... any idea ..??

Comment: Your Gremlin Server stills logs that it tries to use `conf/gremlin-server/titan-berkeleyje-server.properties` although you changed that to `conf/gremlin-server/titan-berkeleyje-server.properties`? And you did restart it after changing the config, right?

Comment: yes i restarted it ,I am doing thiss on centos VM, i did the same setup in another vm , which is working perfectly,, will there be any settings in system for this.

Comment: Sorry, but I never used CentOS. I would just copy the complete Titan folder from the VM where it works to your CentOS VM and see if it works there. Then you know for sure if the problem is specific to CentOS.